# Average of Array Read From txt File

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to read the information from the text file. The text file contains columns of of information. I have gotten to the point of being able to convert them into a String Array and I can print each column by itself. But now when I converted the String Array to a Double array I get errors because the text file contains the letters "T". I wish to skip over them some how. My main goal at this point is to find the average of the MaxT and MinT  columns individually from the text file. Thank you I have been stuck on this for a while

[This is the text file being read from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOtW1.jpg)

```
Day MaxT    MinT    AvgT    Dept    HDD CDD Prep    NewSnow
1   61  38  49.5    17.8    15  0   0.00    0.0
2   60  33  46.5    14.7    18  0   0.93    0.0
3   60  36  48.0    16.0    17  0   0.80    0.0
4   36  22  29.0    -3.1    36  0   T   T
5   43  18  30.5    -1.8    34  0   0.00    0.0
6   47  22  34.5    2.1 30  0   0.00    0.0
7   53  31  42.0    9.4 23  0   0.00    0.0
8   45  23  34.0    1.2 31  0   0.27    2.1
9   24  15  19.5    -13.5   45  0   0.14    2.0
10  18  11  14.5    -18.7   50  0   0.03    0.7
11  25  11  18.0    -15.4   47  0   T   T
12  28  18  23.0    -10.6   42  0   0.01    0.2
13  19  10  14.5    -19.3   50  0   T   T
14  21  11  16.0    -18.1   49  0   0.17    2.9
15  36  21  28.5    -5.8    36  0   T   0.0
16  38  25  31.5    -3.1    33  0   0.02    0.0
17  36  26  31.0    -3.8    34  0   T   T
18  44  27  35.5    0.4 29  0   0.00    0.0
19  66  39  52.5    17.1    12  0   0.00    0.0
20  72  49  60.5    24.9    4   0   0.00    0.0
21  59  41  50.0    14.1    15  0   1.57    0.0
22  50  33  41.5    5.3 23  0   0.00    0.0
23  56  32  44.0    7.5 21  0   0.02    0.0
24  61  33  47.0    10.2    18  0   1.03    T
25  37  32  34.5    -2.6    30  0   0.04    0.5
26  38  31  34.5    -2.9    30  0   T   T
27  52  27  39.5    1.7 25  0   0.00    0.0
28  66  42  54.0    15.9    11  0   T   0.0
29  60  38  49.0    10.8    16  0   0.21    0.0
```

[This is the code I have written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk8EU.jpg)

```
String dataFileName = "inputtxt";

BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFileName));

String line;

bReader.readLine(); // this will read the first line

String line1=null; // this will skip the first line

while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {                 
    //Splitting the content of tabbed separated line        
    String datavalue[] = line.split("\t");

    double[] numbers = new double[datavalue.length];
    // Converts datavalue string array to numbers double array      
    for(int i = 0;i < datavalue.length;i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(datavalue[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(numbers[0]);
}
```

Comment: could you please copy and past the code and text file in the question.

Comment: Yes I can, sorry this is the first question I have posted before

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the "T" is supposed to be ignored. The main-difficulty here isn't ignoring the "T". Setting up that filter can actually be pretty simple:

```
for(int i = 0;i < datavalue.length;i++)
{
    if(!datavalue[i].equals("T"))
    {
        //all "T"s will be filtered out
        numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(datavalue[i]);
    }else{
        //???
    }
}
```

The main-problem will be to mark the cells with "T" as invalid values. A few solutions would be possible:

- since you only want to calculate the average, you can as well simply ignore the values instead. As long as you don't want to create a table that keeps track of all read values, this should do.
- Select a specific value as marker for invalid values
- keep an additional table (`boolean`) that contains a valid-tag for each value
- keep a list with indices of invalid values

Though in your case the entire problem would be a lot simpler:
You only need to process "minT" and "maxT". These table-rows apparently don't contain any "T"s. So instead of bothering with filtering the invalid values and marking them, you could simply parse the two fields that are required for calculating the average-values and ignore the rest of the input.

Calculating the average:

```
//here we sum up the values of each column
double[] sum = new int[columnCount]; //columnCount = number of columns in the table

//count the number of valid values
int[] valueCount = new int[columnCount];

//initialize IO, etc.
...

while(...){
    //read lines, etc.

    for(int i = 0;i < datavalue.length;i++)
    {
        if(!datavalue[i].equals("T"))
        {
            //all "T"s will be filtered out
            numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(datavalue[i]);

            sum[i] += numbers[i]; //add the value to the sum of values in that column
            valueCount[i]++; //increment count of valid values      
         }
     }
}

//calculate the average for each column
double[] average = new double[columnCount];
for(int i = 0 ; i < columnCount ; i++){
    average[i] = sum[i] / valueCount[i];
}
```

The idea is to take the arithmetic mean of each column by summing up all values of that column and afterwards dividing the sum by the number of values that were summed up. We keep track of the sum in the array `sum` (by column) and of the found values in `valueCount`. After running through the file, we can easily calculate the mean from the collected data.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will give this a try

Comment: @Robert I've added another point to the solution for marking invalid values. Might be important.

Comment: This did work thank you again. The columns that do contain the letter "T" I will eventually have to use later on in the program so the filter you provided works great

Comment: @Robert Glad to help you :)

Comment: I just saw your other post I will look over it, thanks again for pointing that out

Comment: Paul, I do have one more question if that is ok. I have been searching for over an hour now on a issue I am having with this but having no luck. I am trying to combine all of the numbers with in the single array index so I can multiply to find the average. I can not find anything online relating to this question if you could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thank you again

Comment: @Robert I think the task is to find the arithmetic mean? That's actually pretty simple: sum up all values, and divide the sum by the number of values. `(x1 + ... +  xn) / n` would be the arithmetic mean of `n` numbers. Just maintain one variable for the sum and another to store the number of values that have been read. I can provide code for this as well, but please try it on your own first

Comment: Thank you I will try this this out

Comment: Paul, I have tried to figure this out but I can't find a solution. I know that I can figure out how to get the the average or mean once I get a sum of one of the arrays index. But that is my problem. I just can't figure out how to take my index of multiple values and sum them

Comment: @Robert I'll edit the answer with the appropriate code.

Comment: @Robert Hope this explains it. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Paul thank you so much. I was having issues finding anything online relating to find the sum of the values. That was the only thing that was holding me back. I know I could figure out the mean but I just couldn't figure out how to actually get the values in the single index summed up so I could apply the math to it. I will give this a try. Thank you again.

Comment: Paul I am having an issue with the code, when you talk about [columnCount] am I suppose to replace that with the amount of columns like [0,1,2,3....] or do I put the total of columns [9] or is columnCount the actual name for the array. Also when you said the while... ect. are you referring to the "while" that I had started with in the code I originally posted

Comment: @Robert `columnCount` is the total of columns in the file. So in your case 9. The `while`-loop is just exactly the same as in your code. I've omited the parts that will remain unchanged.

Comment: Paul, thank you it worked! I have been trying to get this figured out for a couple days now. Now I can finally move on to the rest of my project

Comment: Paul would there be any way to display these numbers into a Jlabel with in  a Gui? I have already created the Gui, It's very simple. You click one button and it is suppose to display those numbers below. I am thinking that I have to convert them into a string?